# Python 3: ImportError “No Module named Setuptools” [ubuntu 14.04 LTS]

Tags: python3

I am trying to upgrade mnemosyne (http://mnemosyne-proj.org/).

I had to install Python3 (a named dependency; the code for mnemosyne has as of this upgrade moved to Python3). I've had no issue with previous upgrades and so believe this issue may be related to Python3.

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and am admittedly a little out of my depth here. No doubt there is not enough info here to find a solution, so please ask and I will update with new info.

When executing setup.py with:

```
sudo python3 setup.py install
```

I am coming up against the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 2, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, Command
ImportError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

I have read widely (including [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426491/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-setuptools/16511140](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14426491/python-3-importerror-no-module-named-setuptools/16511140#16511140) made back in 2013), tried a heap of suggestions and have narrowly avoided (unintentionally) trashing my Ubuntu install.

Attempted fixes include;

```
sudo apt-get install python3-setuptools
python3-setuptools is already the newest version.

sudo apt-get install python3-pip
python3-pip is already the newest version.

sudo pip3 install --upgrade setuptools
The directory '/home/jumblut/.cache/pip/http' or its parent directory is
not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please
check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with
sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/home/jumblut/.cache/pip' or its parent directory is not
owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the
permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you
may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /usr/local/lib/python3.4  
/dist-packages
```

Python3 info:

```
which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Extra Info - Permissions

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.4$ ls -l
total 4
drwxrwsr-x 7 root mygroup 4096 Dec 16 21:55 dist-packages
```

EDIT2: Extra Info - `wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python3.5` errors

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python3.5
--2016-12-19 00:36:50--  https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py
Resolving bootstrap.pypa.io (bootstrap.pypa.io)... 151.101.80.175
Connecting to bootstrap.pypa.io (bootstrap.pypa.io)|151.101.80.175|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 12746 (12K) [text/x-python]
Saving to: 'STDOUT’

100%[=============================================================================================>] 12,746      --.-K/s   in 0.006s  

2016-12-19 00:36:50 (2.02 MB/s) - written to stdout [12746/12746]

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 436, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 432, in main
  File "<stdin>", line 347, in download_setuptools
  File "<stdin>", line 368, in _resolve_version
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 466, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 489, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1324, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

EDIT3: Extra Info - `sudo python3.5 ez_setup.py` errors

```
sudo python3.5 ez_setup.py
[sudo] password for jumblut: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ez_setup.py", line 436, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "ez_setup.py", line 432, in main
    archive = download_setuptools(**_download_args(options))
  File "ez_setup.py", line 347, in download_setuptools
    version = _resolve_version(version)
  File "ez_setup.py", line 368, in _resolve_version
    resp = urlopen(meta_url)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 466, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 489, in _open
    'unknown_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1324, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: https>
```

Comment: Update: After a ton of fiddling (including installing additional packages) I recompiled python3.5 as I had the first time (nothing relating explicitly to SSL) and voila it worked! I now have other issues but they're independent of this one. I'll endeavour to simplify my learnings in an answer which sums it all up.

Comment: @jumblie Please add your solution as an answer.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entirety of the conversation that was taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50307/discussion-on-question-by-jumblie-python-3-importerror-no-module-named-setupto).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer*: After much trial and error, I was able to resolve this issue. Because I tried a lot of different things, this is my best guess at what the actual fix was.

**Its important to note I installed Python3 by compiling the source code rather than installing from the repos (apt-get)**. I had to do this as Python v3.5 is not currently available in the repos for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I have broken the answer down into two parts; *Stuff which is good to know* which provides a lot of background info which may often be assumed knowledge (as a newbie these were lessons I learnt along the way) and the actual *solution*.

**Stuff which is good to know**

- There are two main releases of Python and these can live happily with each other side by side: Python 2.x and Python 3.x. Python 2.x is usually run with `python` whereas Python3.x is usually run with `python3`. You can check the specific version of each with `python -V` and `python3 -V`. Make sure you're using the version you think you're using.
- You can check which version will be installed from the repos prior to installation by using `apt-cache policy <package name>`. This is a great way of avoiding the mess of having multiple versions of the same packaage installed, especially Python. It is also fundamemtal to work out whether you can install via the repos or if you have to track down the source code for the version you are after.

*Sidenote: Attempting a clean-up of multiple Python versions by removing/uninstalling unwanted versions is dangerous and you can potentially brick your system if you don't know what you're doing as Python is a core OS component.*

- When compiling from source, it is up to YOU to ensure you've got all the required dependencies depending on your needs (the benefits of using apt-get is that this usually all gets sorted for you). NB: If you install a dependency **after** you compile, you will have to recommpile before you'll be able to use it.

**The Solution**

Install the following ***before*** compiling the Python source code:

`sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev 
libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils`

Download and compile the source code for your Python version of choice from [python.org](https://www.python.org/downloads/). Compile instructions are normally found in the *readme*.

Verify your version of Python with;

`python -V` and `python3 -V` for Python 2.x and Python 3.x respectively.

Install pip (a tool for installing and managing Python packages);

`wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -O - | sudo python3`

Check pip corresponds to your version of Python;

`pip3 --version`

Install setuptools with;

`wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/ez_setup.py -O - | sudo python3`